# How do I create an inset shadow overlay that is specific to left side of div?

Tags: html, css

I would like to create an inset box shadow on the left side of a div. This shadow needs to overlay on top of the div content.

I've tried using the box shadow and inserting an .png of the the shadow effect but cant get either to work properly. Here's what I've tried:

CSS

```
.inner-shadow-left {
  box-shadow: inset 10px 0 10px -5px black;
}
```

I'm trying to reach this effect:

[image: expectation]

Comment: Can you post your code (HTML+CSS) please

Comment: .inner-shadow-left {
     box-shadow: inset 10px 0 10px -5px black;}

Answer (score 0):

It should work when you set the `box-shadow` to `inset`. This changes the shadow from an outer shadow to an inner shadow. Check out this code snippet.

```css
.box-shadow {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: brown;
  box-shadow: inset 15px 0 20px -10px #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-shadow">Test</div>
```

Comment: Since this replicates the basic original code it doesn't seem like this is the answer.

Comment: Thanks I got the inset in the box- shadow down. It over the content inside the div. was looking for something similar to a z-index to the box shadow.